# how to find packages that have a couple of the same dependencies?

Tags: debian, package-management, dependencies

my specific need: I'd like to find any debian packages that have *both* ncurses and portaudio as dependencies (not just among the ones installed on my machine).

How could I search for that kind of combination of dependencies?

Comment: This should be possible with `aptitude` ex. `aptitude search '?depends(ncurses)?depends(portaudio)'` but I can't verify it (I'm on Ubuntu - there doesn't seem to be a `portaudio` package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) [suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551479/how-to-find-packages-that-have-a-couple-of-the-same-dependencies#comment1023752_551479),

```
aptitude search '?depends(ncurses)?depends(portaudio)'
```

will search for packages depending on both `ncurses` and `portaudio` (strictly speaking, [on packages matching those search strings](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchDep), *i.e.* with `ncurses` or `portaudio` in their name).

In Debian 10 the only match is [`freemat`](https://tracker.debian.org/freemat).